# SQL double group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I need to select employees' names from those who has sold products, for the biggest total sum of money in each of the years, in Northwind database. I've managed to create a valid query like this:

```sql
    WITH TEMP_QUERY AS
        (
            SELECT
                DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS 'Year'
                ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'Employee'
                ,SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) AS 'Total year sale'
            FROM Employees
            INNER JOIN Orders
                ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
            INNER JOIN [Order Details]
                ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
            GROUP BY FirstName + ' ' + LastName, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate)
        )
    
        SELECT
            DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS 'Year'
            ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'Employee'
            ,SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) AS 'Total year sale'
        FROM Employees
        INNER JOIN Orders
            ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
        INNER JOIN [Order Details]
            ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
        GROUP BY
            FirstName + ' ' + LastName
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate)
        HAVING SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) IN
        (
            SELECT MAX(main.[Total year sale]) FROM TEMP_QUERY AS main 
            INNER JOIN TEMP_QUERY AS e ON e.Employee = main.Employee
            GROUP BY main.Year
        )
        ORDER BY 1;
```

However I wonder if there's a simpler way of doing this with or without CTE (probably is)
Database scheme.
https://docs.yugabyte.com/images/sample-data/northwind/northwind-er-diagram.png

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] is this? Can you share the schema?

Comment: https://docs.yugabyte.com/images/sample-data/northwind/northwind-er-diagram.png

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that a question here is supposed to be self-contained, i.e. no external sites should be required.

Comment: Microsoft SQL  server management studio

Comment: Microsoft SQL server management studio isn't a DBMS, it's an IDE like application, used often with SQL Server.

Comment: Oh ok now i kkon that i use Relational database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your main query is the same as those one used in CTE (except `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses), so you can just write it as `SELECT ... FROM temp_query`.

Second, I suggest you not to use the combination of `FirstName` and `LastName` for aggregation in CTE, since in theory there can be multiple rows for different employees with same values. You have the `EmployeeId` you a free to use it instead.

Third, since now the main query does not have any aggregation, you do not need a `HAVING` clause, it can be replaced by `WHERE` clause.

Fourth, the filter condition (in `HAVING` clause of your query) does not need self joining of CTE for getting the maximum of `Total year sale`. Just select `MAX("Total year sale")` with `GROUP BY year`.

Fifth, since I have suggested to use `EmployeeId` to perform the aggregation in CTE, join the `Employees` table to get the corresponding `FirstName` and `LastName` values for an employee in results.

Finally the query would look like this

```
WITH employee_total_sales (
    SELECT 
        e.employeeid,
        DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS year, 
        SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity) AS total_sale 
    FROM Employees e
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    GROUP BY e.employeeid, DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate)
)
SELECT 
    year AS "Year",
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS "Employee",
    total_sale AS "Total year sale"
FROM employee_total_sales ets
JOIN employees e ON e.employeeid = ets.employeeid
WHERE total_sales IN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(total_sale)
    FROM employee_total_sales
    GROUP BY year
)
ORDER BY year
```